# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LocalStorageService

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to upgrade to latest Angular, and I got the error on my component and going to URL /login

it something like this : 
**ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LocalStorageService: (?).**

my pages/login/login.component something like this :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { LocalStorageService } from "ngx-webstorage";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import {
  SnotifyService,
  SnotifyPosition,
  SnotifyToastConfig
} from "ng-snotify";

import { AuthenticationService } 
  constructor(
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private router: Router,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService,
    private snotifyService: SnotifyService
  ) {}
```

and on pages/login/login.module

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login.component";
import { AuthService } from "../../../services/base-services/auth.service";
import { AuthenticationService } from "../../../services/authentication.service";
import { SnotifyModule, SnotifyService, ToastDefaults } from "ng-snotify";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { LocalStorageService } from "ngx-webstorage";

export const LoginRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    data: {
      breadcrumb: "Login"
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: LoginComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: "Login"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(LoginRoutes),
    SnotifyModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    LocalStorageService,
    AuthenticationService,
    AuthService,
    SnotifyService,
    { provide: "SnotifyToastConfig", useValue: ToastDefaults }
  ]
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

and on my app.module is something like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthComponent } from "./layout/auth/auth.component";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AuthGuardService } from "./services/base-services/auth-guard.service";
import { AuthenticationService } from "./services/authentication.service";
import { BreadcrumbsComponent } from "./layout/admin/breadcrumbs/breadcrumbs.component";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, AuthComponent, BreadcrumbsComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [AuthGuardService, AuthenticationService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

is there something wrong for import and put services on my files ?? or any missing syntax on my component ??

my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "kontrak-hukum-front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0-rc.4",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.20.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^2.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.36.0",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^3.0.2",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^3.0.0-beta.1",
    "angular-io-slimscroll": "^2.3.3",
    "angular2-chartjs": "^0.5.1",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-material-datepicker": "^0.5.0",
    "angular2-notifications": "^2.0.0",
    "angular2-wizard": "^0.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "c3": "^0.7.0",
    "core-js": "^3.1.2",
    "css-animator": "^2.3.1",
    "d3": "^5.9.2",
    "echarts": "^4.2.1",
    "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "ng-auto-complete": "^4.1.7",
    "ng-click-outside": "^4.0.0",
    "ng-snotify": "^4.3.1",
    "ng2-auto-complete": "^0.12.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "^5.3.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-nvd3": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-order-pipe": "^0.1.5",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ng2-ui-switch": "^1.0.2",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^7.5.0",
    "ngx-echarts": "^4.1.1",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^5.1.0",
    "ngx-quill-editor": "^2.2.2",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^3.0.2",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "peity": "^3.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "screenfull": "^4.2.0",
    "squeezebox": "^1.4.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.11.4",
    "ti-icons": "^0.1.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "wijmo": "^5.20191.606",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0-rc.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your `package.json`?

Comment: just update, :D @DánielBarta

Comment: Did you figure it out? No answers have been marked yet. If you did something differently then you can update your question as well and mark it.

Answer (score 3):

Your `LocalStorageService` has a dependency that is unmet. You will need to add that dependency to your `login.module`.

As you stated; the `LocalStorageService` is an external package.

Instead of `providing` the `LocalStorageService` yourself, maybe you should `import` the `Module` it belongs to. Probably the `LocalStorageModule`, you may consider putting this in your `app.module` so you can `provide` the service to your locally scoped modules.

Edit: From their README:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webstorage

```
import {NgxWebstorageModule} from 'ngx-webstorage';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [
        ...,
        NgxWebstorageModule.forRoot(),
        ...
    ]
})
```

Then you don't have to provide the `service` yourself, you can just use it in your `constructor()` and it'll be injected.

Comment: LocalStorageService is a package from 'ngx-webstorage',, i did regsiter LocalStorageService in provider login.module

Comment: Updated the answer after you explained it's an external package. You shouldn't be providing the service yourself, you should be importing the `module` it belongs to. See the updated answer for an idea how.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that `ngx-webstorage` does not yet support Angular 8.x.x. There is already a [pull request on github](https://github.com/PillowPillow/ng2-webstorage/pull/105) to change that. I can't think of anything else, as long as you run the application in a browser.

Answer (score -1):

Before using the localStorageService in any component you need to import its module into AppModule or LoginModule.

```
  LocalStorageModule.forRoot({
     prefix: 'my-app',
     storageType: 'localStorage'
  })
```